# ActiveRecord destroy has_many :through record from relational table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many-through

Logistic & Rental Requests belong to each other via a TypeLogistic table. I accidentally created a bad TypeLogistic, so now there are two:

```
TypeLogistic.where(rental_request_id:200).where(logistic_id:130)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<TypeLogistic rental_request_id: 200, logistic_id: 130, type_of_logistics: nil>, #<TypeLogistic rental_request_id: 200, logistic_id: 130, type_of_logistics: "delivery">]>
```

How do I destroy the first one? Tried running below, didn't work

```
TypeLogistic.where(rental_request_id:200).where(logistic_id:130).first.destroy
PG::Error: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "type_logistics" WHERE "type_logistics"."" = $1
                                                            ^
```

Comment: Why not just `TypeLogistic.find_by(rental_request_id: 200).destroy`?

Comment: Hmm, this looks like a AREL bug unless there is something really weird going on with your schema.

Comment: so... i'm screwed? are there potentially other ways of fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is being thrown because the TypeLogistic join table does not have a primary key. Incidentally, this is the default setting it appears, since I followed the instructions to create the join table without altering anything.

Detailed info here: [Rails Devise PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659752/rails-devise-pgsyntaxerror-error-zero-length-delimited-identifier-at-or-near)

Solution? Add a primary key, see this answer below:

[Add Id column in a migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548746/add-id-column-in-a-migration)

Comment: Worth noting that this can also happen if you add to a relation for a join table, which I just ran into.

e.g. if you have Book, Author, and a joining model called BookAuthor, on Author you'd have `has_many :book_authors` and then a has_many :through for the relationship to the books. If you have `has_many :book_authors, dependent: :destroy`, that's wrong and the dependent destroy shouldn't be on the has_many that associates to the joining model.